Generating large records of number sets
I am trying to generate around 10 billion unique records of number set data
Table:
CREATE TABLE GenNumbers
(
NumID BIGINT
,Number1 INT
,Number2 INT
,Number3 INT
,Number4 INT
,Number5 INT
,Number6 INT
)

Insert:
INSERT GenNumbers (NumID, Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4, Number5, Number6)
SELECT NumID
        ,Number1
        ,Number2
        ,Number3
        ,Number4
        ,Number5
        ,Number6
FROM (
SELECT
    S.Value AS NumID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 1 THEN N.Number END) AS Number1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 2 THEN N.Number END) AS Number2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 3 THEN N.Number END) AS Number3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 4 THEN N.Number END) AS Number4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 5 THEN N.Number END) AS Number5,
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 50) + 1 AS Number6
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10000000000) S --10 Billion
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        S2.value AS Number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY R.Randomizer) AS RowNum
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) S2
    CROSS APPLY(
        --SELECT CHECKSUM(NEWID(), S.value, S2.value) AS Randomizer
        SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT(NEWID(), S.value, S2.value)) AS Randomizer
    ) R
) N
GROUP BY S.Value
--ORDER BY S.Value
) GN;

Error:

Msg 5373, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
All the input parameters should be of the same type. Supported types are tinyint, smallint, int, bigint, decimal and numeric.
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 48
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with void type
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 48
Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with void type

I am able to generate 50 million records without seeing the error but as soon as I exceed 100 million records I see the error pop up after awhile.
I assumed I was seeing the error due to my "NumID" was being INT so I changed it to BIGINT which still seems like it didn't work.

What's the purpose of this? Random numbers are NOT unique by definition. Any valid number has the same chance to appear as the same number. 5 9s have the same chance of appearing as any other 5-digit combination.

I want unique Number Sets per row meaning I don't want any row to have the same set of numbers throughout the table.

In any case, what line throws? Have you tried commenting out specific parts to find which one fails? Googling for the error message suggests GENERATE_SERIES will throw if the types don't match. 1 isn't a bigint so if you pass a bigint as the stop value, you'll get an error. Use bigint varialbes instead of hard-coded values

I want unique Number Sets per row meaning... you mean you want to generate unique permutations? That doesn't explain why you want to precalculate them, or why you don't just use a single incrementing bigint

"All the input parameters should be of the same type." The error is literally telling you the problem. 1 is an int, and 10000000000 is a bigint; int <> bigint.

The start and stop parameters of GENERATE_SERIES have different types. As the docs explain:

The data type for stop must match the data type for start.

SQL Server will try to infer the type of a numeric literal from its value but won't use the type of other parameters to guess what the type is.
To bypass this, pass the values as bigint parameters:
declare @start bigint =1,@stop bigint=10000000000;
select top 10 * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(@start,@stop); 

